# TYPO3 (Fluid): Generate FAL-SVG-Image as inline code

Tags: typo3, fluid

Is there a fluid pendant to the new TS option [Feature: #82091 - Allow inline rendering in SVG content object](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Feature-82091-AllowInlineRenderingInSVGContentObject.html) or a workaround?
The only solution i see(atm) is to write my own viewhelper or i am missed something?

Comment: Have a look into EXT:bootstrap_package. Benjamin has already an InlineSvgViewHelper:
https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/InlineSvgViewHelper.php

Answer (score 7):

You can define a typoscript object in your root template:

```
lib.inlineSvg = SVG
lib.inlineSvg {
  renderMode = inline
  src.field = src
}
```

(see [SVG cObject](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Svg/Index.html)). Then in your fluid you can do this:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.inlineSvg" data="{src: 'path/to/the/file.svg'}" />
```

Of course this limits you to cases in which you have the actual path to the image. You cannot (directly) reference a FAL object. You can, however, just get the files public url:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.inlineSvg" data="{src: filereference.publicUrl}" />
```

or

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.inlineSvg" data="{src: filereference.originalResource.publicUrl}" />
```

depending on whether you are in Extbase cotext or not (see [the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Frontend.html#get-file-properties)). You can also pass all other options the cObject takes in the `data` argument of the `f:cObject` ViewHelper (e.g. width).